# Input function not working in python script

Tags: python, input

I am a python newcomer and have problem with executing my input code. My code is as follows:

```
userInput = input("Hi, What is your name? ") 
print("Welcome {0}, Nice to meet you!".format(userInput))
```

Now the problem is that it runs perfectly fine in `PyCharm 2020`, yet when I try to run it in my `Ubuntu 20.04`'s terminal, it returns the following error:

```
./userIO.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./userIO.py: line 7: `userInput = input("Hi, What is your name? ")'
```

I wonder what could the cause be. Can you please help me find what can cause the problem?

Comment: How are you running it in the terminal? What command are you typing in to run it? I think you're trying to run it as a shell script.

Comment: well, you can use `print(f"Welcome {userInput}, Nice to meet you!")` as the `f` makes it a formatted string. Note that it is note supported before Python 3. I dont know if it will fix your problem.

Comment: @xpDev I don't think that will fix the issue, and their method of formatting the string is completely fine.

Comment: How do you try to *run* it on Ubuntu? `python3 script.py` or just `script.py`?

Comment: I feel like this may just be an issue with how they compile the code. In Windows, its like python3 userIO.py or something.

Comment: @iz_: You are perfectly right. I am sorry for my ignorance. I have spent the whole night learning and unfortunately my mind is not working as expected. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running scripts (e.g. by doing `./script` at a command line), Linux uses a special line known as a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to figure out what program is used to run the script. For example, `#!/bin/bash` for Bash scripts, or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for Python scripts.

If there is no shebang line, Bash will default to running the script in Bash (i.e. as a shell script). Since your script is not a shell script, you get a bunch of errors from Bash attempting to interpret your Python code as a shell script.

To fix this, you need a shebang line, which must be the first line of your script. For a Python 3 script, you may use `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, e.g. as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
userInput = input("Hi, What is your name? ") 
...
```

Alternatively, you can fix this by explicitly running your script with the Python interpreter, e.g. `python3 script.py`.

Comment: You could mention that the error message reported by the OP are not Python's but come from Bash.

Comment: That's what I wrote..Got two down votes instead..lol.

Comment: @AbhishekRai probably because you assumed the OP was using Python 2 - but that's not the problem at all.

Comment: I guess so, should have been more explicit anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all friends especially `nneonneo` I can solve my problem in either of the two ways as below:

1. If running it as a python script without using a shebang (so that the OS can understand how to run it), I can run the script correctly by typing:

   ```
     me@linuxbox $> python3 userIO.py
   ```
2. If I like to be able to run the script by just typing `./userIO.py`, then  [nneonneo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65194431/2922479) is the best.
   So to find the correct address to my python interpreter I typed: `which python3` In my terminal and applied the terminal's return value (in my case it was: `/usr/bin/python3`) to the beginning of the file's contents as: `#!/usr/bin/python3`, so that I can now execute the file more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your second line of code with:

print(f"Welcome {userInput}, Nice to meet you!")

**This reduces number of columns in your code.**

Comment: OPs question wasn't about reducing the code, but about an error in Ubuntu terminal while it was working in PyCharm. Please add the supporting information on how your answer solves the error in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32919879)